# Keycloak redirect too many times in my loadbalance services

Tags: spring-boot, nginx, keycloak, load-balancing

I'm trying to use keycloak in my load balance service with Nginx.

But when I call service API, I received the error "Too Many Redirects" in browser.

I guess this process should be:

```
1. Request load-balanced to service A 
2. Keycloak in service A redirect to login page
3. Login with password & username
----------------The above is correct----------------------------------
4. Keycloak redirect to the original page but **load-balance to service B**
5. Keycloak in service B redirect to login page
6. Auto login without password
7. Keycloak redirect to the original page but load-balance to service A
8. Keycloak in service A redirect to login page
9. Auto login without password
10. Then loop forever...
```

[bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTWoB.png)

How should I change my keycloak config and fix the bug?

nginx.conf:

```
    http {
      upstream backend{
          server 127.0.0.1:8001 weight=1;
          server 127.0.0.1:8002 weight=1;
      }
      
      ...
      ...
      
      server {
          listen       80;
          server_name  localhost;

          location / {
              proxy_pass http://backend;
              proxy_set_header Host $host;
              proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
              proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          }
          
          ...
          ...

      }
     }
```

And Springboot keycloak config in the application.properties:

```
server.port=8002 # modify by command line

keycloak.auth-server-url=http://172.20.51.25:8080/auth
keycloak.realm=autocv
keycloak.public-client=true
keycloak.resource=oauthtest

keycloak.securityConstraints[0].authRoles[0]=aps
keycloak.securityConstraints[0].securityCollections[0].name= common
keycloak.securityConstraints[0].securityCollections[0].patterns[0]=/*
```

[keycloak client config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVYbD.png)

Answer (score 1):

You should follow the Official Keycloak Guide [Setting Up a Load Balancer or Proxy](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_installation/#_setting-up-a-load-balancer-or-proxy). Also don't forget to add the following configuration as mentioned in the official docs.

- `proxy-address-forwarding`
- Also enable reverse proxy configurations for your configurations.

> Configure your reverse proxy or loadbalancer to properly set `X-Forwarded-For` and `X-Forwarded-Proto` HTTP headers.
> Configure your reverse proxy or loadbalancer to preserve the original `Host` HTTP header.
> Configure the authentication server to read the client’s IP address from `X-Forwarded-For` header. - from [Keycloak Documentation - Identifying Client IP Addresses](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_installation/#identifying-client-ip-addresses)

Comment: Thanks for you answer.But the service A and service B is an application service, not the keycloak service.  I have check the Keycloak Guide [Spring Boot Adapter](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#_spring_boot_adapter) but can't find any solution unfortunately